# ¿Por qué arroja 'java.util.NoSuchElementException' este código?

Tags: java, excepciones

LLevo un día entero intentando encontrar por qué se produce la excepción **NoSuchElementException** al rellenar una matriz con un Scanner desde la consola.

De los dos bloques de código que aparecen, si comento el primero, el segundo si que opera bien sin excepción alguna:

```
    /**************** 1º) INTRODUCCIÓN DIMENSIÓN DEL ARRAY POR CONSOLA  **************
     Pedimos por consola que el usuario introduzca la dimensión del array y filtramos  
    los datos erroneos hasta que introduzca un número entero mayor que cero.   
    **********************************************************************************/ 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int longitud_array = 0;
    int contador = 0;
    System.out.println("¿Cuántos valores quiere almacenar en el Array?");
    do {
        //El siguiente condicional no se se ejecuta la primera vez
        if (contador > 0) {
            System.out.println("\"" + longitud_array + "\"" + " no es un número entero mayor que cero.");
            System.out.println("Por favor introduzca la longitud que quiere que tenga el Array:");
        }
        contador ++;
        while (!sc.hasNextInt()) { //en este while se filtran todas las capturas de teclado que no sean enteros.
            String caracter = sc.next();
            System.out.println("\"" + caracter + "\"" + " no es un número entero mayor que cero.");
            System.out.println(" Por favor introduzca la longitud que quiere que tenga el Array:");
        }
        longitud_array = sc.nextInt();
    } while (longitud_array <= 0);//Aquí llegan solo los enteros y ya re-filtramos para quedarnos sólo los >0.
    sc.close();


  /**************** 2º) INTRODUCCIÓN VALORES DEL ARRAY POR CONSOLA  *********
   Pedimos por consola que el usuario introduzca el valor de los elementos 
  del array 'A' y creamos dicho array. 
  ****************************************************************************/ 
  int[] A = new int[longitud_array];
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduzca los valores del array A:");
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        A[i] = sc2.nextInt();
     }
     sc2.close();
     System.out.print("Matriz A = {");
     for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
         if (i < (A.length - 1)) {
             System.out.print(A[i] + ", ");
         } else {
             System.out.println(A[i] + "}");
         }
     }
```

Comment: El problema lo tienes porque ambos `Scanner` usan el mismo `InputStream` y cuando cierras uno, dejas al otro sin poder leer. Usa solamente un `Scanner` para capturar los números y ciérralo cuando ya no lo necesites más.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Efectivamente tu respuesta soluciona mi duda.

Comment: @GlennSandoval Deberías ponerlo como respuesta, puesto a otros les podría servir...

Comment: @MrDave1999  ¿El autor de la pregunta no puede marcarlo como respuesta?

Comment: @HOTOMOL Lo puso como comentario, ahí no se puede marcar la respuesta. Si gustas, puedes autoresponder tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Ambos `Scanner` usan el mismo `InputStream` y cuando se cierra uno, dejaba al otro sin poder leer.

Solución: Abrir sólo un `Scanner` y cerrarlo cuando no se vaya a usar más en la clase.